# Textbox with numbers only

Tags: angular, html

I can see all over following suggestion is recommended for having a textbox with numbers only:

```
 <input  formControlName="imo" class="form-control" pattern="\d*" maxlength="8">
```

But for me I can enter characters and are not restricted to numbers only. I am using latest version of Crome. Is this a side affect of the formControlName in my Angular app or have I misunderstod the pattern part?

Comment: why not using  input[type="number"] ?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator

Comment: Thanks @niklaz. I would be happy too. But then I cant control the max length of the number. I need users to be ablle to input only 5 digits.

Comment: Ok, then use <input type="number"  minLength="1" maxLength="5" />

Comment: or <input type="number"  minLength="5" maxLength="5" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pattern` just checks if the value is valid or not, it does not interfere with what user is typing. If you want to allow only numeric values, and that digits entered aren't more than 5 (as you say in comment), then you can do this:

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="imo" (keypress)="checkValue($event)">
```

and the function:

```ts
checkValue(event) {
  return event.target.value.length === 5 ? event.preventDefault() : 
    String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(/[^0-9]/g) === null
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwtjfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

This will actually block the input. If it's suitable with not blocking values, you can go ahead and use `Validators.pattern()` and then just show an error message when user types something they shouldn't.

Comment: That was I expected. That you needed some kind of javascript checking for each key press. But gives the functionlaity I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to hear I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<input type="number" formControlName="imo" class="form-control" min="1" max="5">
```

Comment: Thanks. Number and maxlength does not work together.

Comment: I tried that too. And as you I would expect that to work like that. However I can enter 9999999 for following: <input [(ngModel)]="group.imageX" style="width: 80px;" type="number" min="0" max="100" name="x" placeholder="%"> . I dont know if it is Angular preventing default behavior of HTML 5 or the two of us has misunderstood the use of min max.

Comment: Well, it will let you enter any number but it wont be valid

Comment: Thanks @GaryB. What does that mean its not valid? I just tried in Angular and it dosent trigger any errors on Reactive forms. So I need to prevent the user for submitting. <div class="col-md-9">
            <input  formControlName="dwt" class="form-control" type="input" min="0" max="99">
            <div *ngIf="submitted && editForm.dwt.errors">
                <div *ngIf="editForm.dwt.errors.required" class="form-error">DWT is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: But it is little off the original question. Would like to stick to HTML5 attributes if possible. If I set type as number it prevent user from adding anything else. I would expect same with max and min?

Comment: for the first one:
I used to disable the submit button if the form is not valid: <button[disabled]="!this.form.valid"> Submit</button>
for the second one, if the user using the steppers on the input it will work but if they keying a number it wont

Answer (score -1):

Hello have you tried this below

\d+ instead of \d*

Comment: Consider moving these kinds of answers to be only in comments, since it's not sure to be useful for the developer who asked.